# Play WebSockets Server Push example

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0, push-notification

Can anyone give me an example for Pushing events(as it happens) from the Server to the Client using WebSockets and Play? I am a bit confused about how an event triggers the server-push and how client Enumaretors are maintained while waiting for the trigger.

eg: Look if changes have been made to a file every 5 mins and notify client if changes have been made.
or 
Push each keystroke of user to client using websockets.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the `websocket-chat` project in the `samples` directory of Play.

This sample project is available for Java and for Scala.

Comment: I went through the websocket-chat example. I wanted to know if the same could be done without using Akka.